# Why does starring a question take more time than upvoting it on SO?

Tags: discussion, status-norepro, stack-exchange, bookmarks, up-votes

I have noticed this many times.

> If you star a question, upvote it and then quickly refresh the page, the upvote is reflected while the star is not.

What can be the reasons for that? I am guessing they could be specific to how star and upvote buttons are programmed, but still I am not too sure that is the case. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe because no rep is involved in starring and rep is number 1 priority? Just a guess though.

Comment: @thyrgle: `starring => no rep is involed => less calculations => it should be faster`?

Comment: I don't know just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this -- on SO, I upvoted, then starred, then hit F5 as fast as I could.

Question showed upvote and favorite, as expected, after page reloaded.

I suspect it might be due to network latency?

Are you starring very large questions (30+ answers) or questions that are unusual in some way?

Comment: I think because I am using much slower internet connections sometimes (likes of 128kbps or 16kB/s).